# In the AWS Appsync resolver, is it `$util.` or `$utils.`?

Tags: aws-appsync

The AWS Appsync documentation seems to use `$util.` and `$utils.` interchangeably.  Are they actually different, or synonyms of the same thing?

Best example is the [the resolver transformation helpers documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html#transformation-helpers-in-utils-transform) where they appear side by side...

[image: screenshot of appsync developer guide]

Comment: I've been wondering the same for quite some time now, but couldn't get a clear answer via the documentation. Thanks for posting the question

Comment: Appsync documentation is horrible, so it's not a big surprise. Run away from AppSync! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do both. It's like ctx and context, they are interchangeable.